# from a html form to javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form that requires three inputs as follows:

```
  <form>
    <input name="mn" 
           type="number"
           min="1"
           value="1">
    <input name="mx" 
           type="number"
           min="2"
           value="10">
    <input name="step" 
           type="number"
           min="1"
           value="1">
    <input onclick="myfunc()"
           type="submit"
           value="calculate">
  </form>
```

all i require is to be able to access the three fields directly in javascript. I do not need to pass the information anywhere else.

Could anyone point me in the right direction? I have read examples where there has been one input, but not multiple.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function myfunc() {
    var mn = document.getElementsByName("mn")
    var mx = document.getElementsByName("mx")
    var step = document.getElementsByName("step")
    alert((mn + mx) / step)
    }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give your form an id like so

```
<form id="myForm">
```

The other thing to watch out for is that the is that the `value` attribute is a string so adding the two values concatenates them rather than summing them.

Try instead

```
var frm = document.forms["myForm"];

var _mn = parseInt( frm["mn"].value );
var _mx = parseInt( frm["mx"].value );
var _step = parseInt( frm["step"].value );

var result = ( _mn + _mx ) / _step;
```

Comment: Careful, the values will be strings, so `frm["mn"].value + frm["mx"].value` will concatenate the values, not add them. Convert them to numbers first, e.g. using `parseInt`, `Number`, `+`.

Comment: @RobG Thank you for that. Well spotted. Corrected my code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with giving each input an id then i could use:

```
var min = document.getElementById('mn')
```

and so on. To access the value you simply would call

```
min.value
```

Also there is no point in removing the i from min and the a from max. That is not optimized just hard to read and understand.

Answer (score 0):

if u need to access to the values of the inputs change your code to:

```
function myfunc() {
  var mn = document.getElementsByName("mn")[0];
  var mx = document.getElementsByName("mx")[0];
  var step = document.getElementsByName("step")[0];
  // you may need to validate your values here, like step.value != 0
  alert((mn.value + mx.value) / step.value)
}
```

Comment: And you are dealing with strings, so: `(Number(mn.value) + Number(mx.value)) / step.value` unless concatenation is required.

Comment: I consider that as validation

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function myfunc() {
    var mn = document.getElementsByName("mn")[0].value;
    var mx = document.getElementsByName("mx")[0].value;
    var step = document.getElementsByName("step")[0].value;
    var top = mn / mx;
    alert(top / step);
    }
  </script>
```